# PHP Session While loop not working

Tags: php, session

I have this while loop that keeps repeating the same thing without ever stopping, untill it gives me a whole page of errors.

I'll explain a bit of what im doing: I made a BlackJack game, using only PHP. So with the use of 3 different forms, i start the game ( gives me 2 cards and the dealer 1 card), i create a hit button ( gives me 1 card each time i click it ) and a stand form (which will give the dealer cards ). With the use of sessions i remember all cards so they dont get lost upon a button click. And with the reset button i start and destroy the session, so that a new game is possible. All of this works, except the stand button.

It should give the dealer cards untill his points are => 17. But for some reason it keeps repeating untill my whole page is full of errors. I used some different loops:

```
if(FORM_stand("Stand")){
   while( $total_dealer < 17){
   draw_dealer_card();
   }
   list_dealer_hand();
}
```

and

```
if(FORM_stand("Stand")){
   list_dealer_hand();
   do {
      draw_dealer_card();
   } while ($total_dealer < 17);
}
```

I used both of them without sucess.

The draw_dealer_card(); looks like this:

```
function draw_dealer_card() {
    $dealer_card = array_rand($_SESSION["dealer_pile"]);
    $_SESSION["dealer_hand"][$dealer_card] = $_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$dealer_card];
    unset($_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$dealer_card]);
}
```

And the list_dealer_hand(); like this:

```
function list_dealer_hand() {
    foreach($_SESSION["dealer_hand"] as $dealer_card=>$points) {
        echo $dealer_card;
        echo ', ';
    }
}
```

I don't really know what else is important, please let me know if you're missing some information!

Thanks in advance!

Ps: Don't ask why i'm using only PHP, since that's the point of this assignment. (using only, or as much as possible, PHP)

If you're wondering what my erros look like, they come when i press stand, take a couple of seconds to load, then show me these errors over and over again:

`Notice: Undefined index: dealer_pile`

`Trying to destroy uninitialized session`

`Notice: Undefined index: dealer_pile`

EDIT: At the top of my page i run the `session_start();` which only get interrupted if i press the reset button.

EDIT:

`if(!isset($_SESSION["dealer_pile"])) $_SESSION["dealer_pile"] = array(`

```
  2           =>  2,
  3           =>  3,
  4           =>  4,
  5           =>  5,
  6           =>  6,
  7           =>  7,
  8           =>  8,
  9           =>  9,
  10          =>  10,
  'Jack'      =>  10,
  'Queen'     =>  10,
  'King'      =>  10,
  'Ace'       =>  11);`
```

Comment: Are you including `session_start();` at the top of your pages? It seems like your sessions aren't being kept from page to page. (This includes any page the user will go on, even if it's for a split second).

Comment: yes BeatAlex is right... the error says that your session don't even exists.

Comment: @BeatAlex Yes, at the top of my page i have a session_start(); it only stops this one if i press my reset button. My other forms shouldnt've worked either if i didnt declare a session_start right?

Comment: @Dwza Yes, at the top of my page i have a session_start(); it only stops this one if i press my reset button.

Comment: try to empty your session, not destroy it at all

Comment: @Dwza is there any benefit from emptying it instead of destroying it? (im new to sessions)

Comment: yes **[session_unset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)** emptys it or **$_SESSION = false;**

Answer (score 1):

Besides a missing session_start(); you should also set $_SESSION["dealer_pile"]

```
$_SESSION["dealer_pile"] = "foobar";
```

Comment: I have a session_start(); at the top of my page. It only stops the session if press the reset button.

Comment: And are you also setting $_SESSION["dealer_pile"] somewhere?

Comment: Check my editted question, the array is the session you mean right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It seems like session support is off. Can you try a phpinfo() and check if session support is on.

Comment: Session Support enabled. Is what my phpinfo shows me